# How to fix the hands of Clock in XAML for 8.1 RT

Tags: c#, xaml, clock

The following code doesn't put hands at center. Is there a better way to make it layout correctly by not hardcode coordinates too much in XAML?

```
            <Grid x:Name="ClockGrid" Grid.Row="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Width="270" Height="270" >
            <Image Source="Assets/backGround.png"/>
            <Rectangle Margin="0,-125,0,0" Width="3" Name="rectangleSecond" StrokeThickness="3" Stroke="White" Height="100">
                <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                    <RotateTransform x:Name="secondHand" CenterX="0" CenterY="120" Angle="0" />
                </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
            </Rectangle>

            <Rectangle Name="rectangleMinute" Margin="0, -100,0,0" StrokeThickness="3" Width="4" Stroke="LightGreen" Height="80">
                <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                    <RotateTransform x:Name="minuteHand" CenterX="0" CenterY="90" Angle="0" />
                </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
            </Rectangle>
            <Rectangle Name="rectangleHour" Margin="0,-80,0,0" Width="5" StrokeThickness="5"  Stroke="LightYellow" Height="60">
                <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                    <RotateTransform x:Name="hourHand" CenterX="0" CenterY="70" Angle="0" />
                </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
            </Rectangle>
        </Grid>
```

My behind code:

```
        private void Clock_Tick(object sender, object e) {
         secondHand.Angle = DateTime.Now.Second * 6;
         minuteHand.Angle = DateTime.Now.Minute * 6;
         hourHand.Angle = (DateTime.Now.Hour * 30) + (DateTime.Now.Minute * 0.5); }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is similar to what you did, but polylines were used to draw the clock hands rather than Rectangles. The grid is a 144 x 144 square and each hand is centered in it. You could say it involves more "hard coding", but hey, it does the job!

```
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"
        Width="144" Height="144">
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Polyline">
            <Setter Property="Stroke"
                    Value="{StaticResource ApplicationForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
        </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <Border BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="2"/>

    <Polyline Points="72 80, 72 24" StrokeThickness="6">
        <Polyline.RenderTransform>
            <RotateTransform x:Name="hourHand" Angle="0" 
                                CenterX="72" CenterY="72" />
        </Polyline.RenderTransform>
    </Polyline>

    <Polyline Points="72 88, 72 12" StrokeThickness="3">
        <Polyline.RenderTransform>
            <RotateTransform x:Name="minuteHand" Angle="10" 
                                CenterX="72" CenterY="72" />
        </Polyline.RenderTransform>
    </Polyline>

    <Polyline Points="72 88, 72 6" StrokeThickness="1">
        <Polyline.RenderTransform>
            <RotateTransform x:Name="secondHand" Angle="30" 
                                CenterX="72" CenterY="72" />
        </Polyline.RenderTransform>
    </Polyline>
</Grid>
```

[image: Fancy Clock]

Code behind:

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();

    DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
    timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;
    timer.Start();
}

private void Timer_Tick(object sender, object e)
{
    DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Now;
    this.hourHand.Angle = 30 * dateTime.Hour + dateTime.Minute / 2;
    this.minuteHand.Angle = 6 * dateTime.Minute + dateTime.Second / 10;
    this.secondHand.Angle = 6 * dateTime.Second + dateTime.Millisecond / 166;
}
```

Courtesy of: Charles Petzold - "Programming Windows 6 ed"

Comment: Thank you! Also just in case, there is a typo in the code: "this.hourHand.Angle = 30 * dateTime.Hour * dateTime.Minute / 2;" Should be "this.hourHand.Angle = 30 * dateTime.Hour + dateTime.Minute / 2;"

Answer (score 1):

I would use Grids for the hands (with no background), set to fill width and height, with rotation transforms perfectly centered. Then you can drop whatever you like onto each grid to represent the hand itself. Here is an idea with just one hand:

```
    <Grid Width="100" Height="100">
        <Grid RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
            <Grid.RenderTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <ScaleTransform/>
                    <SkewTransform/>
                    <RotateTransform Angle="20"/>
                    <TranslateTransform/>
                </TransformGroup>
            </Grid.RenderTransform>
            <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="10" Height="60" Fill="#FF42F00F" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
```